# Add text above shape using Sketch

Tags: text, shapes, sketch-app, line-art

**Problem:**

Trying to add text above a shape line in Sketch so that the text only cuts parts of the shape line.

**Current design:**

[image]

**Desired design:**

[image]

What are the necessary steps in order to get the text to cut the line below?

Comment: I can explain to you multiple ways how to achieve this in Sketch app, but have you thought about how you/your programmer is going to achieve this in code?

Comment: This is actually only an illustration that I use to learn more about how to use the Sketch app.

Comment: I have answered similar question, please check: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78693/how-to-make-rectangle-with-text-in-its-border/78699#78699

Comment: Jane.... it's just a fieldset and legend in HTML. Fairly standard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make rectangle with text in its border?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78693/how-to-make-rectangle-with-text-in-its-border)

Answer (score 2):

This might be an over-simplified answer but could you could have a white, borderless rectangle cover the yellow border and put text on top of that?

Then you could group the text and border if you want to resize later.

[image: Text over border]

Answer (score -1):

You can check this post to get a rough idea that how you can cut an image behind he text:
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/overlap-text/